# JRE version is 1.6.0; version 1.7.0 or later is needed to run Google Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

I have 3 versions of Java installed on my system: 6, 7, and 8... I am required to have JRE6 available for a product my company develops, so I cannot get rid of it... But despite copying my Eclipse install to a new folder for another project I need to work on and removing JRE6 from this version alltogether, I still cannot get it to work.

[image]

How can I get the google plugin for Eclipse to work in my scenario?

Comment: The Installed JREs are used when running other Java programs from within Eclipse. What you need to change is the JRE that Eclipse itself is running - which can be specified in the eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created a shortcut to start eclipse, you can add a parameter to tell it to use the jre of your choice like this -

```
C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Programs\jdk\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javaw.exe"
```

I have used "javaw" executable from a jdk installation, but you may point to the same executable within a JRE installation as well.

This will resolve the error.

Comment: That did it... but as a more permanent solution, I put it into the eclipse.ini: -vm /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin/java

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that there is a separation between the JVM that Eclipse itself is running in and the various JREs that you can configure *in* Eclipse to run your programs/applications. You need to specify to Eclipse what JVM you want it to run under, using [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

That's separate from the Installed JREs configuration you show in your screen shot above.

Answer (score 0):

Add Java 7.0 to Eclipse if you haven't: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

Next add Java 7.0 library to your project: Right click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Remove JRE 1.6 and add New Library (JRE System Library, 1.7.0).

Last set Java 7.0 compliance level: Right click on project -> Preferences -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level: 1.7

Also since you can use different Java to run applications, you also have to change this in the Run configuration which you use to start AppEngine related tasks.

Comment: That's exactly what I already tried... see the screenshot above.

Comment: You might also have to change the run configuration if a different Java is set there. This might also relieve you from change the Java you use to start Eclipse.

Comment: @Carl Indeed, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Is it OK to run using Java 8 or does GPE  require specifically Java 7?